Create type depending on Type<Param>
type ToConcat<M> = {}

const mid1:ToConcat<{foo:'bar'}> = {}

const mid2:ToConcat<{john:'doe'} = {}

Is there a way to have:
const finalObject = [mid1, mid2, myAttempted] 

where myAttempted will be the concat of mid1 and mid2?
{
 foo: 'bar',
 john:'doe
}

Here is what I tried, but it does not work:
type Mid<L> = {
    locals: L
}

type Fi<M extends Mid<any>[]> = {
        [key in keyof M[number]['locals']]: M[number]['locals'][key]
}

const mi1:Mid<{foo:'bar'}> = {
    locals: {foo: "bar"}
}
const mi2:Mid<{john:'doe'}> = {
    locals: {john: "doe"}
}

type P<R extends Mid<any>[]> = [...R, Fi<R>]

const g:P<[typeof mi1, typeof mi2]> = [mi1, mi2, {
    locals: {
        // it does not work 
    }
}]

My final attempt is just to get a type with the need to declare mid1 and mid2 as objects.

• What type should ToConcat<M> actually be? You don't want it to be {}, that's the empty object type and doesn't depend on M, which does very weird things. • Why are you doing this with a tuple type? Does needing to place something at the end of the tuple really matter to the question as asked? If someone just gave you a way to turn a tuple of types into an intersection of their elements, would that work? Or do you really need to spread tuples around?

Please [edit] to clarify these for future readers; I know you've already accepted an answer (although I'm not sure if it meets your needs; will you ever see unions inside Mid's type argument, like P<[Mid<{a: string} | {b: string}>, Mid<{c: number}>]?) but it would be helpful to make the question as clear as possible for anyone with a similar question as you in the future. Thanks!

You could use a UnionToIntersection utility to merge array items (converted to a union) (you can remove Simplify, it's for debugging here)
Playground
type Mid<L> = {
    locals: L
}

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (arg: U) => any : never) extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type Fi<M extends Mid<any>[]> = Simplify<UnionToIntersection<M extends Mid<infer A>[] ? {
    [key in keyof A]: A[key]
} : never>>;

type Simplify<T> = {[K in keyof T]: Simplify<T[K]>} extends infer A ? A : never;

type Mis = Simplify<[typeof mi1, typeof mi2]>;

const mi1:Mid<{foo:'bar'}> = {
    locals: {foo: "bar"}
}
const mi2:Mid<{john:'doe'}> = {
    locals: {john: "doe"}
}

type P<R extends Mid<any>[]> = [...R, Fi<R>]

const g:P<Mis> = [mi1, mi2, {
    foo: 'bar',
    john: 'doe'
}]


And if the tuple elements are themselves unions?
